# Specifying timestamp or date format in AWS athena Table

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have a timestamp in `ISO-8601` format and want to specify it either as a `timestamp` or `datetime` format when creating a table in Athena. Any clues on how to do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [create table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html) in Athena you can set a column as date or timestamp only in the Unix format as follows:

> - DATE, in the UNIX format, such as YYYY-MM-DD.
> - TIMESTAMP. Instant in time and date in the UNiX format, such as
>   yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]. For example, TIMESTAMP '2008-09-15
>   03:04:05.324'. This format uses the session time zone.

If the format is different, define it as a String and when you query the data use the [date function](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html):

> from_iso8601_date(string) → date

You can convert the data to make it easier and cheaper for specific use cases by using [CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) (create table as select) query that will generate a new copy of the data in a simpler and more efficient (compressed and columnar) parquet format. You can also make a view that parses the column.

There are some more considerations around dates when it comes to partition keys. See also this [overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html#data-types-timestamps) of working with dates.